# document ready not working when I have 2 jquery libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, syntax

I used a plugin that includes

> jquery-1.12.4.min.js

as one of its resources. But in my project, I am using

> jquery-3.4.1.min.js.

In order for them to not have a conflict, I did this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>var $x = jQuery.noConflict();alert("Version: "+$x.fn.jquery);</script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>var $y = jQuery.noConflict();alert("Version: "+$y.fn.jquery);</script>
```

Even if the function `noConflict()` is working - due to the fact that the version of the respective jqueries can be seen on alert, I get an error pointing to the `$(document).ready(function(){`. I guess I have to specify which version will I use? If yes, how? I can't find for the syntax to do it. Please help...

Comment: bro you must use only one jquery

Comment: @FrancisCordova If you'd just read the article you've linked: "_the method releases the $ sign to be used [by] other JavaScript frameworks_". That is, simply use an identifier you've defined (`$x` or `$y`) for no-conflicting jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, better replace `$.noConflict()` with `$.noConflict(true)` to indicate that you want all jQuery instances to be removed from the conflicted  name.

All of that, makes it possible to use `$y` and `$x` to refer jQuery with an exact version.

So instead of `$(document).ready(function(){`

You would do `$y(document).ready(function(){` or `$x(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

You have used the noConflict function properly but you cannot use '$' in variable name, as calling noConflict function released '$' variable to be used by another javascript frameworks.

change your variable names to x an y and give it a try.

Also you cannot use `$(document).ready(function(){` as you have already changed the alias of the jquery $ variable to x and y in your case.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>var x = jQuery.noConflict();</script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>var y = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
x(document).ready(function(){

alert('ready from :' + x.fn.jquery);
});

y(document).ready(function(){

alert('ready from :' + y.fn.jquery);
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your efforts. I have figured out how to retain the $ on the former codes that I wrote. What I did was:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>var $ = jQuery.noConflict();alert("Version: "+$x.fn.jquery);</script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>var $y = jQuery.noConflict();alert("Version: "+$y.fn.jquery);</script>
```

Since I used $ as a container for the jquery version that I have been using for my project, I won't need to change the codes beginning with $ on my original codes.

But in order to use the older jquery version which was used by the plugin I integrated with my project, I must use $y (   e.i. $y(document).ready(function(){ }); and $y('#field1id').val();     ).

My project is already working now. Thank you for the inputs.